# how can i return the value after forwardslash from string

Tags: ruby

I have a string `"/com.bing.bang/20140620%2F351811403305411724"`

I am trying to seperate `"com.bing.bang"` and `"20140620%2F351811403305411724"`

Simple `.split['/']` won't work because string starts with "/"

How this can be done?

Comment: `str.split('/')` gives `["", "com.bing.bang", "20140620%2F351811403305411724"]`. What’s wrong with that?

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
_, *arr = s.split '/'

arr
#=> ["com.bing.bang", "20140620%2F351811403305411724"]
```

Comment: Very clever, very clean!

Comment: Really interesting things in this answer... the use of the "unused variable" `_`, the use of variable number of arguments `*arr` on the left of a multiple assignment... very cool.

Answer (score 1):

Split will work if you simply remove the leading `/` before you use it:

```
str = "/com.bing.bang/20140620%2F351811403305411724"
fst, snd = str[1..-1].split('/')

fst # => "com.bing.bang"
snd # => "20140620%2F351811403305411724"
```

**Also** `str.split['/']` doesn't do anything useful, it in fact raises an exception, because split is a method. To call it you must use parentheses (rounded brackets) like so: `str.split('/')`.

The reason for the exception is that the former expression actually looks like this to the interpreter: `(str.split)['/']` so it will split `str` on its spaces, and then it treats the `['/']` as an index into the array that is produced from the split.

This is a problem because the index you gave it is a string, and arrays only accept `Integer` indices, so you end up getting a `TypeError` raised.

Comment: Could I get an explanation as to the downvote please?

Comment: Taking a substring before splitting is unnecessary and assigning the result to `fst`, `snd` assumes that the substring will only have one `/`. Santosh's answer is both more general and more elegant.

Comment: This answer applies to the question however, in which we have been given only one test case. It is simply an alternative route, it is not wrong. As to the elegance, that, I would say, is subjective. Personally, I prefer avoiding variables, so, I took the substring first. And as to the generality, my answer *does not* assume only one delimiter, it simply always gives you the first and second parts, even if there are more (try it)

Answer (score 1):

```
x = "/com.bing.bang/20140620%2F351811403305411724"
bits = x.split("/")
bits.shift if bits[0] == "" # dump the initial ""
(part1,part2) = bits
```